# What does a "3" next to a note mean?

Tags: rhythm, cello

I have no idea what the "3" next to a quarter note means, thanks.[image]

Comment: It's shabbily written. The bar under that then seems to be 9/8. Has the time sig. changed?

Comment: Yes, it changes to 9/8.

Comment: Whilst it happens to be a dupe, the dots are so badly written, it may be useful to leave it in as an example...

Comment: It's pretty well written for a *hand copied* part, compared with some I've seen! There is too much random variation in the individual symbols for it to have been engraved, either before or after computer engraving.

Comment: @alephzero - fair enough, I was thinking of the lines that should encompass the triplets. They're just not good - probably the easiest bit to do when hand writing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a triplet marker.

If you tally up the note lengths in this bar, you'll see that they don't add up to 4/4. The crotchet and quaver between which the "3" is printed are supposed to be shorter than usual so that 3 rather than 2 notes to a crotchet are played. This makes the rhythm add up again. (The same goes for the last quaver in the bar.)